# Hashes with repetitive keys only

Tags: ruby

```
hashes = [{:auchan=>2.3, :biedronka=>2.6, :lidl=>2.4},
          {:auchan=>2.5, :biedronka=>3, :lidl=>2.4, :zabka=>3.5},
          {:auchan=>1.5, :lidl=>1.1, :zabka=>2},
          {:auchan=>1.1, :lidl=>0.8, :zabka=>1.5, :biedronka=>1.6}]
```

I want to get hashes with only repetitive keys.

I tried this, but it is good for only 2 hashes, not more:

```
hashes[0].merge hashes[1].select { |k| hashes[0].keys.include? k }

hashes.same_keys => [{:auchan=>2.3, :biedronka=>2.6, :lidl=>2.4}, 
                     {:auchan=>2.5, :biedronka=>3, :lidl=>2.4 }, 
                     {:auchan=>1.1, :lidl=>0.8, :biedronka=>1.6}]
```

Comment: Are you asking for an `Array` method `same_keys`? Also, please explain (by editing) what you mean by "repetitive keys" and show the desired result for your example, explaining why some hashes were included and others were not.

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly find keys and then map your hash:

```
same_keys = hashes.map(&:keys).reduce(&:&)

hashes.map { |h| h.slice(*same_keys) }
=>[{:auchan=>2.3, :lidl=>2.4},
   {:auchan=>2.5, :lidl=>2.4},
   {:auchan=>1.5, :lidl=>1.1},
   {:auchan=>1.1, :lidl=>0.8}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but assuming you want an array where each input hash maps to a hash containing only the keys that are present in *every* hash in the input, the below should work:

I've tested this in Ruby 1.9.3, but it should work in more recent versions too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'set'

hashes = [
  {:auchan=>2.3, :biedronka=>2.6, :lidl=>2.4},
  {:auchan=>2.5, :biedronka=>3, :lidl=>2.4, :zabka=>3.5},
  {:auchan=>1.5, :lidl=>1.1, :zabka=>2},
  {:auchan=>1.1, :lidl=>0.8, :zabka=>1.5, :biedronka=>1.6}
]

keys = nil
hashes.each do |h|
  if keys.nil?
    keys = Set.new(h.keys)
  else
    keys = keys & h.keys
  end
end
puts keys.to_a

result = hashes.map do |h|
  h.select{|k,v| keys.include?(k)}
end

puts result
```

Also if you are trying to save bytes, you can set `keys` with this oneliner instead:

```
keys = hashes.map(&:keys).reduce{|t, h| t & h}
```